# Alternatives to using .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm currently working within a dataframe and although the code works, the current routine takes around 1 hour to complete. Based upon claims_data having 130K rows and contract_data_shaped having 600 separate rows.
Rough outline of routine is as follows:

1. Gather the data into df
2. Create a list of 600 custom objects taking the object attributes from an underlying dataframe.
3. Apply a UDF to each of the 600 objects, element wise, across all 130K rows of claims_data and create columns for each output, again element-wise using .apply()

I know this is probably awful code but could somebody please indicate how I could perhaps speed this up? Is there some other way to write this function so that it vectorises the operations somehow please?
Class and UDF as follows held within RI.py:

```
class XOL:

    """This is a generic which returns non-proportional recoveries"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get("name")
        self.attachment = float(kwargs.get("attachment"))
        self.limit = float(kwargs.get("limit"))
        self.classes_covered = kwargs.get("classes_covered")
        self.uwy_covered = float(kwargs.get("uwy_covered"))
        self.placed = float(kwargs.get("placed"))
        self.currency_covered = kwargs.get("currency_covered")

    def calculate_recovery(self, **kwargs):
        # global recovery
        if (float(kwargs["gross_loss"]) >= self.attachment) & \
                (kwargs["actuarial_class"] in self.classes_covered) & \
                (kwargs["uwy"] == self.uwy_covered) & \
                (kwargs["currency"] == self.currency_covered
                ):
            return (min(kwargs["gross_loss"], self.limit) - self.attachment) * self.placed
        else:
            return 0
```

Main.py code as follows:

```
                                                              axis=1)
from RI import XOL
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import xlwings as xw


claims_data_path = "S:/Actuarial/Reserving/2022/2205/Financial Lines/Five Segments/Data/Reserving Policy Detail - Financial Lines 2205 v1.xlsx"
contract_details_path = "P:/WIP/Net Down/FinLinesContractDetails.xlsx"


fx_rates = pd.DataFrame(xw.Book(claims_data_path, update_links=False).sheets["Lookups"].range("H4:I180").value)
fx_rates.columns = fx_rates.iloc[0]
fx_rates = fx_rates[1:]
fx_rates = {row[0]: row[1] for index, row in fx_rates.iterrows()}

# Map the existing Actuarial classes to the RI mapping of three buckets
required_class_dict = {"Financial Lines - Commercial D&O": "D&O",
                       "Financial Lines - TRI": "W&I/TRI",
                       "Financial Lines - Cyber": "Cyber",
                       "Financial Lines - Commericial PI": "D&O",
                       "Financial Lines - Financial Institutions": "D&O",
                       }

claims_data = pd.DataFrame(xw.Book(claims_data_path, update_links=False).sheets["Reserving Policy Detail"].range("A3:BA128292").value)

claims_data.columns = claims_data.iloc[0]
claims_data = claims_data[1:]
claims_data["Adjusted Class"] = claims_data["Actuarial Class"].map(required_class_dict)


# multiply all relevant amount column by -1
col_list = ["Gross_Paid_Losses",
            "Gross_Outstanding_Losses",
            "Gross_Incurred_Losses",
            "Net_Paid_Losses",
            "Net_Outstanding_Losses",
            "Net_Incurred_Losses"]

# swap sign convention of claims numbers
for col in col_list:
    claims_data[col] *= -1

contract_data = pd.read_excel(contract_details_path, header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1, 2])

# Remove zero rows from the contract data mapping
contract_data = contract_data.loc[(contract_data.sum(axis=1) != 0), :]

contract_data_shaped = contract_data.stack(level=1)\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "Alias",
                     "level_1": "Treaty Year",
                     "level_2": "Currency",
                     "Currency": "Class"}
                    )
contract_data_shaped.to_csv("P:/WIP/Net Down/contract_data_shaped.csv", index=True, header=True)
# Chop the contract data down to save processing time - those contract terms = 0 placed
contract_data_shaped = contract_data_shaped[contract_data_shaped["Placed"] != 0]

# create a list of XOL contract objects, each defined by their attributes as loaded by the input files
contract_obj_list = [XOL(name=index,
                         attachment=row["Attachment"],
                         limit=row["Limit"],
                         placed=row["Placed"],
                         classes_covered=row["Class"],
                         uwy_covered=row["Treaty Year"],
                         currency_covered=row["Currency"])
                     for index, row in contract_data_shaped.iterrows()
                     ]
# apply each contract in the contract list of instantiated XOL objects to each and every claim
recovering_contract_list = []
for contract in contract_obj_list:
    claims_data[f"Contract_ID_{contract.name}"] = claims_data.apply(lambda x: contract.calculate_recovery(
                                                                gross_loss=float(x["Gross_Incurred_Losses"]),
                                                                actuarial_class=x["Adjusted Class"],
                                                                uwy=x["Underwriting_Year"],
                                                                currency=x["Currency"]),
                                                                axis=1)
```

Comment: Pandas eval is pretty useful for vectorizing mathematical operations on large datasets. [eval](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html)

Comment: This seems a bit too verbose, detailed and specific for a StackOverflow question. Could you rephrase it, simplifying the problem and boiling it down to a minimal example of the mechanism you are looking for?  Otherwise, you should ask at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and include an example we can work with. It's pretty much impossible to test code without inputs/expected outputs.